# Decrease page margins on minipage

Tags: margins, minipage

I'm having following problem:
I have two pictures side by side with minipage. Annoyingly this creates a margin on either side of the minipages, which is much bigger than the normal page margin. Is there a way to reduce this?

My Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\graphicspath{{Grafiken/}}

\begin {document}

etc etc

\begin{figure} [hbt!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics [width=.8\linewidth]{A1B1} 
    \caption{Aufschluss Westbahnhof}
    \label {fig:A1B1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics [width=.8\linewidth]{A1B2} 
    \caption{Einzelner Pflasterstein}
    \label {fig:A1B2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

etcetc

\end {document}
```

[image]

I'd basically like to adjust the margin on the minipage sizes so it fits more with the margins of the main document.

Cheers
Anton

Comment: I guess it's because of all the `\centering` commands, when you remove them there is no extra margin for the minipages.

Comment: Or leave the `\centering` but change the minipage width to `0.49\textwidth` each, that also effectively removes the extra margins.

Comment: minipage never adds any margin but you specified `\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}` so at most 90% of the text width is used up by minipage and you specified that the image only uses 80% of that. so only 72% of the text is image and 28% plus the usual page margins is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't run your example (you could use `example-image` as the image as it's generally available but it perhaps helps to annotate the spaces (just looking at the block within `\textwidth` assuming the overall page margin is OK)

[image]

Your total minipage space is only 90% of the text width and the images only take up 80% of that already reduced space

I would set the minipage width to `.5\textwidth` and remove the word space between the two with `...\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}...` with no space, then make the images a bit wider say `0.9\linewidth` so 90% of the already wider minipage.